# Evitar dejar el gridview oculto cuando no hay resultados en la busqueda

Tags: java, android, textview, searchview, android-gridview

En mi app implemente un SearchView. Logré hacerlo funcionar perfectamente pero me surgieron varias dudas al verlo funcionar:

Necesito un mecanismo para cuando no haya resultados me muestre un textview que no hay... entonces hice lo siguiente

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() { 

    @Override 
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) { 
        return false; 
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) { 

        serviceAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText); 

        if (serviceAdapter.getCount() <1) { 
            findViewById(R.id.tvNoResult).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            gridView.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
        }else{ 
            findViewById(R.id.tvNoResult).setVisibility(View.GONE); 
            gridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
        } 

        return true; 
    } 
});
```

Agregué un TextView oculto en mi xml y en el java hice una condicion que decía que si el adapter era menor que 1 ocultara el GridView y mostrara el TextView, todo funcionó como esperaba pero el problema es que cuando presiona el botón atrás o el de cerrar, el SearchView se me queda el TextView visible y entonces me dificulta el funcionamiento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así es como queda después:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es: ¿existe algún método para trabajar con el botón atrás y el de cerrar el SearchView? ¿Qué puedo hacer para evitar que suceda esto?

Comment: Sería mejor mostrar un alertdialog al usuario y así evitas modificar el XML además es más fácil de manejar. Si no podrías agregar una función al boton back que al presionar vuelva el textview a gone. No no he probado pero debería funcionar.

Comment: Pense en lo mismo , pero realmente me hace falta mostrar el textview , me haria falta saber cual es el metodo que trabaja con el boton atras y con el boton de cerrar , lo conoce ?

Comment: Cuales son los métodos que utilizas para implementar la funcionalidad de los botones de volver hacia atrás ⬅ ❌?

Comment: Podrías añadir tú código por favor

Comment: @Davidminaya eso es lo que necesito saber cual son los metodos que usa para poder poner que cuando  se ejecute ponga nuevamente el textview GONE y el grdview visible

Comment: @AshleyG. que parte del codigo ?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tienes que hacer es volver a hacer visible el `GridView` cuando presiones el botón de volver atrás, dependiendo cual botón presiones el lugar donde deberás hacer visible el `GridView` sera diferente.

Por ejemplo si presionas la tecla back del dispositivo, tendras que sobreescribir el metodo `onBackPressed()`, que es el que se ejecuta al precionar dicha tecla.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    findViewById(R.id.tvNoResult).setVisibility(View.GONE); 
    gridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Y si es presionando la fecha de volver atrás de la barra de acciones de la aplicación, tendrás que sobrescribir el método `onOptionsItemSelected()` que es el que se ejecuta al presionar una de las opciones de la barra de acciones. El id de la opción de volver hacia atrás ⬅ es `android.R.id.home`.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        findViewById(R.id.tvNoResult).setVisibility(View.GONE); 
        gridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

#### Actualizacion

Para hacer visible el `gridView` cuando precionas la **X** del `SeachView` debes implementar la interface `OnCloseListener` de este.

```
searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {

        findViewById(R.id.tvNoResult).setVisibility(View.GONE); 
        gridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
        return false;
    }
});
```

---

Puedes encontrar un sencillo ejemplo de como hacerlo [aquí](https://gitlab.com/david-minaya/RespuestasStackOverflow/blob/master/app/src/main/java/davidminaya/respuestasstackoverflow/MainActivity.java).

Comment: oh muchas gracias.... y si toca la X para cerrar , ahi es donde esta el gran problema , mira que he buscado y no se cual metodo controla eso..

Comment: Añade el xml del menú, el id de la ❌ debe estar hay. Si no vas a utilizar mas opciones en esa actividad, puedes quitar el `if` que esta dentro del `onOptionsItemSelected()`, de esa manera al pulsar cualquier opción del menú el `GridView` se hará visible y el `TextView` no, aunque es una solución, no es aconsejable.

Comment: como tal no conozco el id de X pq eso viene con el mismo search view..

Comment: Quita el `if` del método `onOptionsItemSelected()` y listo.

Comment: lamento decirte que ```@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        findViewById(R.id.tvNoResult).setVisibility(View.GONE); 
        gridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}``` no funciono para interceptar ese boton atras....

Comment: He editado mi respuesta, si quieres una respuesta mas exacta tienes que proporcionar mas información. Agrega la actividad y el xml donde tienes el `seachView`.

Comment: el evento OnClose tampoco funciona... hice una busqueda en google y no soy el primero que tiene ese problema con el evento OnClose...

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta y muestra como tienes el código. Porque a mi si me funciona. Puedes encontrar un ejemplo [aquí](https://gitlab.com/david-minaya/RespuestasStackOverflow/blob/master/app/src/main/java/davidminaya/respuestasstackoverflow/MainActivity.java).